# EmberJS, inspecting objects in a hasMany relation when they are still not loaded

Tags: ember.js, promise, has-many

As part of the workflow of my application I have a conflict situation: one part of my code is trying to find a specific `Object` into a `hasMany` relation that is still not loaded and because of that it is returning `undefined`.

I am using the [Ember.Array.findBy method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_findBy) with the hope it was taking care of all the promises' idiosyncrasy.

This is the line that is failing:

```
this.get('report.charts').findBy('questionId', questionId);
//-> undefined
```

It is clear that at the moment I am invoking this line the `report.charts` are not all loaded:

```
this.get('report.charts').map(function(e){ return e.get('questionId') });
//-> ["Wiese_030", undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Some more info:

```
this.get('report.charts').toString();
//-> "<DS.PromiseManyArray:ember1209>"
```

What is the way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an async relationship (which is default for all relationships in current ember versions) you will always get an `PromiseObject` or `PromiseArray`.

If you are in a computed property you can use it directly, because it will trigger an update. So this is safe code:

```
questions: Ember.computed('report.charts.@each.questionId', {
  get() {
    return get(this, 'report.charts').findBy('questionId', get(this, 'questionId'));
  }
})
```

If you do this in any other context you should *wait for the promise*! So in any hook, actions, etc:

```
get(this, 'report.charts').then(charts => {
  let found = charts.findBy('questionId', questionId);
  ...
})
```

Comment: Even if my proposed solution is better for my actual scenario I think this answer is more globally useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this issue blocking the App in the Route level returning a promise that only resolves when all the elements in the `hasMany` collection have resolved as well.

I had this in my Route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('report', params.report_id);
  }
});
```

And now I have this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    let reportPromise = this.store.findRecord('report', params.report_id)

    let promise = reportPromise.then(report => report.get('charts').then(() => report));

    return promise;
  }
});
```

It works smoothy due the App remains in the *loading* Route until the promise resolves.